# work around for autocomplete="false"

Tags: java, html, browser

In latest update Chrome and IE both has stopped honouring auto-complete attribute. 
Could please suggest any other way through which we can stop user to save password

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try which I have seen works for some people, update might have stopped this too though (im not on the latest version so cant test), is putting the autocomplete in form form tag, instead of in each input, for example:

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="get" ... >
```